# upper case abbreviations converted to lower case

Tags: web-services, ant, xsd, wsdl, weblogic

When we upgrade weblogic to 12c, used "jwsc" ant tool to generate JAX-WS type WSDL and XSD file, the class name which include upper case abbreviations as prefix was converted to lower case in xsd:complexType.

for example:

1. class name is: PINRequest.java
2. use "jwsc" to generate WSDL/XSD: it displays in XSD as complexType name="pinRequest"
3. Using clientgen to generate client jar, the class name changed to: PinRequest.class

Is there any way to prevent this kind of convert?

Comment: it was converted to xsd:complexType name="pinRequest"> in XSD